# Command works in container but not via docker-compose exec

Tags: docker

I'm trying to write a script to do a `mysqldump` and `gzip` the output.

```
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs -d '\n')
filename=$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
docker-compose exec mysql "mysqldump -uusername -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE | gzip > ~/$filename.gz"
```

When I run `mysqldump -uusername -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE | gzip > ~/$filename.gz` directly in the container (via `docker-compose exec mysql bash`), it works. However, when I run the script, I get

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "mysqldump -uusername -ptest123 my_db | gzip > ~/20211121_220309.gz": stat mysqldump -uusername -ptest123 my_db | gzip > ~/20211121_220309.gz: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Is there something about executing a command through `docker-compose exec` that makes it different?

Comment: It seems as though you're trying to execute `mysql` through `docker-compose exec`. Why not just take that part out, and run `docker-compose exec "mysqldump -uusername -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE | gzip > ~/$filename.gz"` directly?

Comment: It looks like you have the various credentials you need already, and you probably want the dump file on your host system.  Can you directly run `mysqldump` (possibly with `-h127.0.0.1`), targeting published `ports:` of your database container, without the `docker-compose exec` wrapper?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The `mysql` you're referencing is the container name. I need to include it so it knows where to run it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to have to install mysql on whatever system this runs. I want to be able to run everything I need directly on any system.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose exec mysql bash -c "mysqldump -uusername -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE | gzip > ~/$filename.gz"`

Comment: This is probably correct, but can you add some text explaining what's different from the original command and why it makes a difference?

Comment: So this worked, but I don't get why. Obviously it's being run directly through bash, but I don't get why it fails on the exec.

Comment: no such file or directory - your command is interpreted as a whole string.